# Getting error while deploying code from local Git to Azure via Azure CLI

Tags: azure-cli

I am trying to push my code from a protected Git repo via Azure CLI, but I am getting the below error:

```
az webapp deployment source config --branch *** --manual-integration --name **** --repo-url ***** --resource-group ****
```

Error

> The server name or address could not be resolved

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deploy code from local Git, please make sure you have installed the [Git](https://www.git-scm.com/downloads), then follow the steps below.

1.Login and configure a deployment user

```
az login
az webapp deployment user set --user-name 'joyw1' --password 'Password01!'
```

[image]

2.Get the deployment URL

```
az webapp deployment source config-local-git -g <group-name> -n <webapp-name>
```

[image]

3.Open a local terminal window to your local Git repository.

[image]

4.Add an Azure remote, replace the  with the one in step 2.

```
git remote add azure <url>
```

Then run the command to push to Azure, it will let you to input the username and password, just input them that you set in the step 1.

```
git push azure master
```

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this doc - [**Local Git deployment to Azure App Service**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-local-git).

Comment: I have deployed the code from git to my app service but when i test my bot in webchat I am getting error:Response Object :StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: '', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Server: nginx/1.12.0
  Date: Thu, 16 Apr 2020 09:56:28 GMT
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: keep-alive
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache, max-age=0
  Pragma: no-cache
  X-Frame-Options: DENY

Comment: @Anu Could you check your if your code was deployed successfully in the wwwroot via the [Kudu console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/benjaminperkins/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites)? If your code was deployed successfully, I think you may need to ask it in a new post, because it is a new issue.